# Power cable of a laptop charger

Tags: charger

A laptop charger has 3 pins - positive,negative,earth at the end which is inserted into the switch board. But, the end inserted into the laptop has only 1 pin(don't know what that is). A battery also positive and negative terminals. So how does this one pin suffice the two pin battery?

Answer (score 3):

That single "pin" is known as a "[barrel connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaxial_power_connector)" and has two contacts — one on the outside and a separate one on the inside.

[image: photo]

The advantage of this coaxial arrangement is that the connector has no preferred orientation, and can even swivel while in use.